# Hosting multisite Wordpress subsites on custom domains

Tags: wordpress, dns, multisite, custom-domain

I have a wordpress multisite eg `www.happy.com` and I have created subsites with subdirectories

```
www.happy.com/site1
www.happy.com/site2
```

I own 2 custom domains from 123-reg.co.uk eg

```
www.sunny.com
www.chocolate.com
```

Currently I have wordpress subsites redirecting

```
Eg: when user types www.sunny.com it redirects 301 to www.happy.com/site1
```

The wordpress subsite shows but it has the url [www.happy.com/site1](http://www.happy.com/site1) and I need it to show as the custom domain `www.sunny.com`

Does anyone know the best way to do this? I tried pointing domain at the hosting server but it didn't work and then wordpress was down for a day so I am conscious not to break again eek.

Thanks in advance